# Run a Visual Studio Project (ASP.NET WebApp) in OSX, possible?

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

is it possible to run an existing Visual Studio Project in OSX ? Just like with the play button in Visual Studio for windows?

Comment: With [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/core) it is possible to run ASP.NET 5 web applications on OS X or Linux with the new Kestrel server.